# ExternalInterface calls only work in the flash debug plugin

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am attempting to use a flash object to proxy info from a server I don't control through the `xmlsocket` class to my javascript. To that end, I have created a small swf that implements all the `xmlsocket` stuff I need and exposes sections of it via `ExternalInterface`. I then embed this swf in my background page and attempt to access the exposed functions.

When I disable chrome's default flash plugin to use the debug version I have installed to get traces and error messages, it works fine. I can call the exposed functions properly and flash can call javascript functions with no warnings or errors, but when I re-enable chrome's default flash, everything stops working.

Here are the relevant pieces of my code:

```
if(ExternalInterface.available){
  ExternalInterface.addCallback('test',test);
  ExternalInterface.call('console.log','test');
}

[...]

public function test() : void{
  if(ExternalInterface.available)
    ExternalInterface.call('alert','test');
}
```

I am really new to anything flash, is there something I need to add to make it work in non-debug flash?

I am using version 13.0.0.214 of both kinds of flash in chrome 34.0.1847.137m on Windows 7.

Edit: I forgot to explicitly say that this is in a chrome extension.

Comment: Are you running this locally or from server? If locally, there is a bug in Chrome's PPAPI FP that seems like won't be fixed. You can run your swf from (local) server or use other browser.

Comment: @Fygo It is running in a chrome extension and I think it counts as local. Using another browser isn't really an option.

Comment: I see. If that's the case I guess you have bad luck. You can try to install the NPAPI version and see if you can use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out why it was working for one flash plugin but not the other. I had previously set some trusted locations in the [global settings](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html) menu, but those didn't apply to pepper flash, so it was causing a security error. Simply adding the trusted location `chrome-extension://` got it working again.